# How to deal with list of JSON data stored in text format in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
create table test (data text);

insert into test values 
( 
    '[{
        "name": "Alexa", 
        "age": "20"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Siri", 
        "age": "42"
    }]' 
);
```

Here data column is of text type (It has list of JSON DATA). I want to change lets say "name" = "Alexa" to "name" = "Cortana". How to do this?

If it would be of JSON type I would have done this.

```
UPDATE test
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{0,name}', '"Cortana"', true)
```

Since data is of text type, do i have to do something like this?

> cast to jsonb -> update that jsonb data -> cast to text -> replace old text to new text

Please suggest any good way to do this.

Comment: `SET data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb, '{0,name}', '"Cortana"', true)::text;`maybe?

Comment: Why using `TEXT` when you can use `JSON` or `JSONB` type ?!?

Comment: senior sde's designed the DB, i am just an intern :|, This is not the actual thing that i am working on but this something i have to use there.